# install iOS app with custom config

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, settings

I'm trying to figure out how to change the config of an iOS app from outside the app or preferably while it is installed. I would like to change the base url of the api for different group of users.

Let's say we have 2 websites (fictive):
bikers.my-app.com
runners.my-app.com

When a biker installs the app from the website, the base api url should be bikers.my-app.com/api/ and runners.my-app.com/api/ for the runners.

From what i've found this is not possible when installing from the AppStore without creating 2 applications.

Is there something like an "app profile" users can install to change app settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned - this is not possible once the app is in the app store. The easiest solution is creating a settings / profile screen that allows users to choose Running or Biking. Then have the app change the URL based on their selection.

Comment: Will wait for other insights otherwise your answer will be accepted.
We wanted to avoid this approach but I'm aware this could be the only option in the end.

Comment: Unless you have two different apps. Though that seems like overkill if the URL is the only difference between the two.